# get second last article joomla

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

I need to use two article latest news module in my joomla 2.5 website. In one module I want to show the last article, while in the second module I want to show the second last article. How can i set this param?
I try to edit the helper.php of mod_articles_news module, but I don't know how to set this param. I suppose I have to add a line like this

```
$model->setState('somwthing', param);
```

but the problem is that I don't know what I have to write. I can use as param variable the variable that rapresent the number of article to show in the module, because i force it to show only one article per module so that param is useless now.
Thanks.

Comment: Why you have to set this values in params. you can list through the query concept.

Comment: Mm.. can you give me an example? Thanks :)

Comment: I think you have to display the latest two news in a module or you have made it on seperate modules

Comment: resolved. I use count parameter (his function in useless for me to get the position of the article, last or second last, and in the helper.php I do a simple if on this param and i use unset function to remove the articles, depending on count param value)

Comment: If you solved the answer means update the answers, It will helpful to all.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this

**mod_modulename.php:**

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php');

$news   = modxxxxHelper::getlatestarticles();
```

**helper.php**

```
class modxxxxHelper
{
    function getlatestarticles()
    {
        $db     =& JFactory::getDBO();  
        $query = 'SELECT title FROM #__content WHERE state = 1 ORDER BY id desc limit 0,1';

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();        

        return $result;
    }

}
```

**default.php**

```
<?php echo $news; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the module settings itself.

Start by creating 2 'Latest Articles' or 'Latest News' modules.

For your **last article**, open the module settings in the backend:

- Set 'Count' to '1'
- Set 'Order' to 'Recently Added First'

For your **second article**, open the module settings in the backend:
 - Set 'Count' to '1'
 - Set 'Order' to 'Recently Modified First'

Then, open the article you want to display as second, add a space at the end of sentence or something and resave.  This will change the modified timestamp to most recent causing it display for the second module for your **second article**